# Navigate to page and trigger some method

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My use case:

After saving the changes on the form, I want to navigate the user to the home page and display for a few seconds message about successful saving. How to do this correct?

My method is simplified like this:

```
async updateOrder() {
      try {
        await this.updateOrder({order: this.order});

        this.$root.$emit("openCompletedMsg", true); <- I try this, but it doesn't work 
        this.$router.push("/");

      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    },
```

So I need show q-dialog on the home page, but after saving my order.

Comment: Have you tried passing a URL param after saving the form and then checking for that param on your homepage?

Comment: No, I haven't tried, is this the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure what is best practice here. But I actually just found this part of the vue-router documentation:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode
Perhaps this way you'll be able to keep your URL clean but still convey the data you need. All you would have to do then is check for a value that you can pass.

Comment: Ideally you would have a global modal, for example in the root App component, that you could trigger from anywhere.  You would trigger this and redirect to the home route at the same time.  Vuex is helpful too